# Getting a specific class instance from a BeanDefinition

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to use Spring to find implementations of an interface with the following method:

```java
public static Set<BeanDefinition> getImplementations(String packageName, Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
        provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(annotation));

        return provider.findCandidateComponents(packageName);
    }
```

This does work and does find my implementing classes (that are annotated and in the specified package). However my final goal is creating a `Map<String, Class<?>>`, where the `String` comes from an annotation on the implementing classes, and the `Class` is the implementer itself. How can I get the annotations and class from a beanDefinition instance? If that isn't (easily) possible how else can I create a `Map<String, Class<?>>` or perhaps a `Map<String, Implementer>` from my  `Set<BeanDefinition>`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the resulting map key (`"String comes from an annotation on the implementing classes"`) is an attribute of the annotation used in  `AnnotationTypeFilter`, you can do something like this (error handling omitted):

```java
public Set<BeanDefinition> getImplementations(String packageName, 
                                              Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
    ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
    provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(annotation));
    return provider.findCandidateComponents(packageName);
}

public Map<String, Class<?>> getImplementationsMap(String packageName, 
                                                   Class<? extends Annotation> annotation, 
                                                   String annotationAttribute) {
    return getImplementations(packageName, annotation).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(beanDefinition -> extractAnnotationAttribute(beanDefinition, annotation, annotationAttribute),
                                      beanDefinition -> extractBeanClass(beanDefinition)));
}

private Class<?> extractBeanClass(BeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
    try {
        return ((ScannedGenericBeanDefinition) beanDefinition)
                .resolveBeanClass(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private String extractAnnotationAttribute(BeanDefinition beanDefinition,
                                          Class<? extends Annotation> annotation,
                                          String annotationAttribute) {
    return ((ScannedGenericBeanDefinition) beanDefinition)
            .getMetadata()
            .getAnnotationAttributes(annotation.getName())
            .get(annotationAttribute).toString();
}
```